# While Loop Concatenation Exercise

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just starting to learn Python and have a question regarding an exercise that came up in the textbook I'm reading.

I found a solution that does function, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler/recommended solution?

Problem:

```
numXs = int(input('How many times should I print the letter X? '))
toPrint = ' '
#concatenate X to print numXs times print(toPrint)
```

My solution:

```
numXs = int(input('How many times should I print the letter X? '))
toPrint = ''
while (toPrint == ''):
    if numXs == 0:
        numXs = int(input('Enter an integer != 0 '))
    else:
        toPrint = abs(numXs) * 'X'
print(toPrint)
```

Comment: It looks quite good to me (but I am not a pro, too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest you get all your data checking and correction handled up front, so your actual algorithm can be much simpler:

```
numXs = 0

while numXs <= 0:
    numXs = int(input('How many times should I print the letter X? '))
    if numXs <= 0:
        print('Enter an integer > 0')

print('X' * numXs)
```

Comment: he used `abs()` to get rid of negatives, thanks for the tip for 'X'

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be

```
try:
    print("x" * int(input("how many times?")))
except:
    print("you entered an invalid number")
```

If you want a zero or negative check

```
try:
    num = int(input("how many times?"))
    if num > 0:
        print("x" * num)
    else:
        print("need a positive integer")
except:
    print("not a number")
```

If you want this to happen forever, just wrap it in a while loop

```
while True:
    #code above
```

Comment: The OP's zero check got lost somewhere in this reimplementation...

Answer (score -1):

You are not handling wrong conversions (input of "Eight") - so you could shorten it to:

```
print(abs(int(input("How many?")))*"X") #loosing the ability to "requery" on 0
```

Same functionality:

```
numXs = abs(int(input('How many times should I print the letter X? ')))
while not numXs: # 0 is considered FALSE
    numXs = abs(int(input('Enter an integer != 0 ')))

print(numXs * 'X')
```

Safer:

```
def getInt(msg, errorMsg):
    '''Function asks with _msg_ for an input, if convertible to int returs
        the number as int. Else keeps repeating to ask with _errorMsg_ until
        an int can be returned'''
    i = input(msg)
    while not i.isdigit():
        i = input(errorMsg)

    return int(i)
```

I am using `isdigit()` to decide if the `input` is a number we can use. You could also do `try:` and `except:` around the `int(yourInput)` so you can catch inputs that are *not* conversible to integers:

```
def getIntWithTryExcept(msg, errorMsg):
    '''Function asks with _msg_ for an input, if convertible to int returs
        the number as int. Else keeps repeating to ask with _errorMsg_ until
        an int can be returned'''
    i = input(msg)  # use 1st input message
    num = 0
    try:
        num = int(i)     # try convert, if not possible except: will happen
    except:
        while not num:   # repeat with 2nd message till ok
            i = input(errorMsg)
            try:
                num = int(i)
            except:      # do nothing, while is still True so it repeats
                pass

    return int(i) # return the number
```

Comment: Missing quotes on your last line of code:  `print(numXs * 'X')`

Comment: @cdlane thanks for the pointer